# Where are the files I need to include in my project in order to write a custom gradle task?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin

I want to write a custom gradle task for my Android Studio project, so I need to get the gradle task classes into my classpath so I can extend Task.  Where are the files that contain those classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, I found the Java src files for the gradle classes here:

C:\Users/*username*/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.4.1-all/*some_hash_or_something*/gradle-3.4.1/src/core/org/gradle/api

Comment: Why do you need the source files to develop custom task types?

Comment: Don't necessarily need source files - jars would be fine too

Comment: If you want to use the Gradle API in a Gradle project, simply add `compile gradleApi()` and `compile localGroovy()` to your project dependencies.

Comment: Thanks!  But in my case it's not a Gradle project, but an existing eclipse java project.  I just want to make some minor alterations to it so that I can use it as a first class gradle task instead of going through the less pretty JavaExec.

Answer (score 0):

As I already stated in a comment, you can use the two dependencies `gradleApi()` and `localGroovy()` to add the Gradle API to your Gradle project.

However, you can use this simple Gradle `build.gradle` file to get the Gradle API JAR files and import them into your non-Gradle Java project:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()
}

copy {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'gradleApi'
}
```

Simply call `gradle` (a task name is not necessary) and you can find the JARs in a subfolder called `gradleApi`.

If you really need to alter Gradle source files, which I'm sure you don't, simply fork the project on GitHub.